# How can I get text labels to show up in a UICollectionView header?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with custom cells, and I want to add a header. I've clicked the option in the Interface Builder and I can place a UILabel in that header, but the label will not show up when I build, compile/run the app. How can I get it to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check out my answer I put here, It's adding a label to a UICollectionView header. Should give you a good idea how to achieve what you're looking for. [Swift 3: Cant programmatically create label on Collectionview header properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989307/swift-3-cant-programmatically-create-label-on-collectionview-header-properly/45427576#45427576)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an custom ID in Interface Builder Identifier field.
[add custom header to collection view swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199528/add-custom-header-to-collection-view-swift)